# Is it necessary to lock the reading object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, stdlist

I'm writing a program which has a shared "queue" of string:

- 2 or 3 threads push back to the queue
- UI thread pop the string from the queue every 0.5 - 1 seconds. (UI thread means CWnd::OnTimer)

One of the writing threads pushes back the string very frequently. (The string is a log, in fact, which is generated 5 - 10 lines per sec.)

I append following code snipet about explanation above.

```
class Logger {
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::list<std::string> m_queLogs;
public:

    int info(std::string zLog) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_mutex);

        m_queLogs.push_back(std::move(zLog));
        ...
    }

    std::string popLog() { //!!!!! Do I need to add a lock_guard here?
        if (m_queLogs.size() == 0)
            return "";

        auto zLog = m_queLogs.front();
        m_queLogs.pop_front();

        return zLog;
    }
}

// Thread 1
int TcpComm::OnRecv(int opCode, char* buf) {

    switch (opCode) {
    case CODE_LOG:                      // generated nearly Real-time 
        Logger::instance()->info(buf);

        break;
        ...
    }
    ...
}

// Thread 2
void MonitorThread(LPVOID lpvoid) {
    while (1) {
        Sleep(60 * 1000);               // generated some times.

        Logger::instance()->info(" ---- monitor signal --- ");
        ...
    }
}


// UI Thread
void CLogView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    // every 500 milisecond.
    auto zLog = Logger::instance()->popLog();
    CString strLog = convert_utf8_to_cstring(zLog);

    m_ctrLogView.AppendString(strLog);
}
```

The strings of `m_queLogs` are never be removed, only pushed back in writing threads.
Only UI thread pops the log from the `m_queLogs`.

I think there is no problem without locking in `Logger::popLog()`, but not sure in case the logging frequency increases.

Please help me to make a decision.

Comment: Yup, you need a lock, for multiple reasons.

Comment: The rule is: If you have shared state, and at least one thread is a writer to that state, then you need synchronization.

Comment: @NathanOliver If I add a lock to the `popLog()`, when the logging frequency increases, the LogView get stuck and flickers, and also `Logger::info` get stuck and the program crashes.
That's why i want to remove lock in `popLog()`.
Is there no solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Reader has to lock in order to avoid writes that are unsequenced in relation to the read which would lead to undefined behaviour.

There may be benefit in looking into non-blocking queue data structure. Multiple writers have to lock I think, but reader can be made wait free. But keep in mind that wait free doesn't necessarily imply efficient.

Comment: If I check `std::list::size() > 0` before pop the log, the locking is unnecessary, i think.
What do you think, sir?

Comment: @codingmonster It's not unnecessary. The call to `std::list::size` must be locked because the writer would be updating it. Also, now that I read it, your reader is actually also a writer because it modifies the list.

Comment: Sorry, again. In my case, checking `std::list::size>0` is not very important. If it goes to empty state, although writer updating the list to `size>0` that moment, reader will pop the log next time. My target is just **to avoid crashing, like 0xc0000005 exception**, and also **speed up the processing**.
There is only one reader, so writing part of reader you mentioned can be ignored, by the `std::list::size>0`. What about this?